# Access denied 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, debian, chef-infra

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf                                               1 ↵
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = #%@u5D2Y0eP5
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = #%@u5D2Y0eP5
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

However when I try to check the status of mysql:

```
$ service mysql status
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I'm confused why it's not using the password I gave?

---

**Mysql**:  14.14 Distrib 5.5.31
**Debian**: Wheezy

Also, [here's my /etc/mysql/my.cnf configuration](http://bpaste.net/show/tkKCEp4kZNC3KtsYurP4/) file.

Comment: How did you install mysql? is the bash script custom?

Comment: @Krishnanunni I used the [check cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql) with the following [config](http://bpaste.net/show/i4MJCI8VrtxCkO6vgHqJ/).

Comment: Have you created a user called 'debian-sys-maint' in mysql? or you just configured it?

Comment: I checked `mysql.user` table and `debian-sys-maint@localhost` is there.

Comment: if you just need to know the status of the server, is a connection must? However, try to grant privileges to this user, like debian-sys-maint@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'

Comment: I just tried granting `*.*` but still the same occurs when I checked the status again. Also if you noticed the error it says '(using password: NO)`. I'm not sure why it's not using a password.

Comment: I changed my password to alphabetic characters only and now it works :|

Comment: I think, since your password string started with '#' it was treated commented. So there would be no readable password. Just notices it now

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my password was having special characters, I tried changing the password to alphabetic ones and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that the password had a `#` character; hash is a comment character in debian.cnf, which uses the mysql configuration file format. You can use a `#` fine in passwords if you enclose the value in quotes. From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html):

> You can optionally enclose the value within single quotation marks or double quotation marks, which is useful if the value contains a “#” comment character.

So this would have been fine:

```
password = "#%@u5D2Y0eP5"
```

Answer (score 0):

change the localhost as 127.0.0.1(loopback)
and try again its wored for me

> host: 127.0.0.1

thank you

Comment: please check that you insertd the correct usernam nd pass.. and also check that you gve permisn to accs the db for the user..

Comment: If I try `mysql --user=debian-sys-maint --password='#%@u5D2Y0eP5'`, I can connect fine.

Comment: mirzmaster.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/mysql-access-denied-for-user-debian-sys-maintlocalhost/

please check this :)
hope you will find the solution from this blog